# Reaction button like facebook in Android

Tags: java, android, position, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I wanna make a reaction button like Facebook, so something like this

[image]

Now i manage to make something similar with a DialogFragment but I am having some trouble with the position of my dialog,  this code sometimes works but some other time the dialog is placed in the wrong place. Can someone give me some advice or suggest me a better way to do this?

***My Dialog Class***

```
public class ReactionsFragment extends DialogFragment {

    public static final String TAG = "ReactionsFragment";
    private  View paretnView;


    public ReactionsFragment(View view, String reviewId,Reactionable reactedContent) {
        this.paretnView = view;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reactions, container, false);
        initComponent(view);
        setDialogPosition();
        return view;
    }


   
    public void initComponent(View rootView) {...}


    public void setDialogPosition() {
        if (paretnView == null) {
            return; // Leave the dialog in default position
        }
        int[] location = new int[2];
        paretnView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
        int sourceX = location[0];
        int sourceY = location[1];
        Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
        window.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = window.getAttributes();
        params.x = sourceX - dpToPx(0);
        params.y = sourceY - dpToPx(110);
        window.setAttributes(params);
    }


    public int dpToPx(float valueInDp) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getActivity().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        return (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, valueInDp, metrics);
    }


}
```

Comment: have you fixed this issue ? I am also using this with popupWindow but I am getting a memory crash due to the multiple lottie files loading at the same time, so getting JNI detected crash in this. Can you please help me out with this, if you are also using lottie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PopupWindow. I think this is exactly what you are looking for:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow

You can set the exact position for the popup to appear using [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow#showAtLocation(android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int))